# Can't find my Data in firebase database, after pushing a new java object from android app

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database

i just use  `reff.push().setValue(trip);` and cannot see any data in the database.while the application is running without any errors.

```
    DatabaseReference reff;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_trip);

        AvailableSeats = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AvailableSeats);
        Destination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Destination);
        Startingtime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TripTime);
        RoadDetails = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Details);
        OtherDetails = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Other_Details);
        SubmitNewTrip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start_New_Trip_Button);
        trip = new Trip();
        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Trip");


        SubmitNewTrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Validate()) {

                    trip.setAvailableSeats(AvailableSeats.getText().toString());
                    trip.setDestination(Destination.getText().toString());
                    trip.setStartingtime(Startingtime.getText().toString());
                    trip.setRoadDetails(RoadDetails.getText().toString());
                    trip.setOtherDetails(OtherDetails.getText().toString());




 reff.push().setValue(trip);


                    Toast.makeText(NewTripActivity.this,
                            "New Trip Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Post your `Trip` model

Comment: Are your project linked with Firebase Database?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman yes it is.

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener? Is something printed out?

Answer (score 0):

check your rules of database. is it public